# QGIS 3 Modeler operate with a fieldname

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, fields-attributes, qgis-modeler

In a model I would use a fieldname of a layer with the Input of Vector Field. When I use the name of the input in an expression, the model gives no result. Do you have any idea?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extract all the vector layer features where `vfeld` equals `'L521-WA91E0*'`, that would be the following expression:

```
attribute(@vfeld) = 'L521-WA91E0*'
```

If the * is supposed to be a wildcard, use:

```
attribute(@vfeld) LIKE 'L521-WA91E0%'
```

Comment: @MrXsquared right. I've updated the expressions accordingly